# NodeJs :Error 401(Unauthorized) i m using passport-jwt

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, jwt, passport.js

i am working on auth application using nodejs mongodb and passport-jwt middle ware passport.authenticate login is working and i get token but when i try to access user profile after login i get Error: 401(Unauthorized) in postman console.

Here is my application code ..

## passport.js

```
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/database');

module.exports = function(passport){
    let opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme('jwt');
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
        User.getUserById(jwt_payload.id, (err, user) => {
            if(err){
                return done(err, false);
            }
            if(user){
                return done(null, user);
            }else{
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    })
     );
  }
```

## users.js

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require("passport");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const config = require("../config/database");
const User = require("../models/user");

//Register
router.post("/register", (req, res, next) => {
  //res.send('REGISTER');
  let newUser = new User({
    name: req.body.name,
    email: req.body.email,
    username: req.body.username,
    password: req.body.password
  });
  User.addUser(newUser, (err, user) => {
    if (err) {
      res.json({ success: false, msg: "Failed to register user" });
    } else {
      res.json({ success: true, msg: "User registered" });
    }
  });
});

//Authenticate
router.post("/authenticate", (req, res, next) => {
  //res.send('AUTHENTICATE');
  const username = req.body.username;
  const password = req.body.password;
  User.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) {
      return res.json({ success: false, msg: "User not found!" });
    }

    User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (isMatch) {
        const token = jwt.sign(user.toJSON(), config.secret, {
          expiresIn: 3600 // 1week  604800
        });
        res.json({
          success: true,
          token: "JWT " + token,
          user: {
            id: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email
          }
        });
      } else {
        return res.json({ success: false, msg: "Worng password" });
      }
    });
  });
});
//Profile
router.get("/profile", passport.authenticate('jwt', {session: false}), (req, res, next) => {
 // res.send("PROFILE");
 res.json({user: req.user._id});
 
});


module.exports = router;
```

## user.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const config = require('../config/database');

//User Schema
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name:{
        type: String
    },
    email:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

const User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

//Getting UserById
module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
    User.findById(id, callback);
    console.log("got user by id");
}
//Gettng UserByUserName
module.exports.getUserByUsername = function(username, callback){
    const query = {username: username}
    User.findOne(query, callback);
}

//AddUser  
 module.exports.addUser = function(newUser, callback){
    bcrypt.genSalt(10,(err, salt) =>{
        bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt,(err, hash) =>{
            if(err) throw err;
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser.save(callback);
            console.log("new user has been added");
        });
    });
} 

//Login or AUTHENCATION 
module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback){
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, (err, isMatch) => {
      if(err) throw err;
      callback(null, isMatch);
      console.log("compare pwd complete");
  });
}
```

any help highly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

return only `token` in `/authenticate`

```
token: "JWT " + token, to

token: token,
```

for request after login need Set the header:

```
Authorization:Bearer {token}
```

Comment: I have exactly this issue and this is the same code am using. Kindly give more info on where exactly to Set ```Authorization: Bearer {token}``` I have the following on the frontend: ```getProfile() {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    this.loadToken();
    headers.append('Authorization', this.authToken);
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    return this.http
      .get('http://localhost:3000/users/profile', { headers })
      .pipe(map((res) => res));
  }```

Answer (score 0):

```
 User.getUserById(jwt_payload.id, (err, user)
```

should be `jwt_payload._id` because it's referring to the id in your mongo database.